# ¿Cómo identifico el causante de Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler?

Tags: java, jaspersoft

Quiero realizar la impresión de un reporte de la clase `Pedido`, para ello cree un `PedidoReporte.jrxml` funcional según el preview de JasperSoft.

Creo una clase llamada `ConexionReporte<E>` para realizar la conexión entre el reporte y los datos de la clase Pedido, además es donde se contiene el método que se encarga de generar el reporte cargado con los datos.

```
generarReporte(List<E> lista, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nombreReporte) throws JRException {
```

Recibo los siguientes parámetros `List<E> lista` que contiene la información para el reporte, luego  `Map<String,Object> parametros` para otras informaciones, y `String nombreReporte` para indicar de cuál reporte se trata.

Al llamar al método `imprimir(Pedido pedido)`, se pasan los datos de la clase `Pedido` que quiero imprimir.

```
private void imprimir(Pedido pedido) {
    HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("nombreEmpresa", "iOS");
    parametros.put("contactoEmpresa", "09853000003");

    pedidos.add(pedido);

    // Creando el reporte
    ConexionReporte<Pedido> conexionReporte = new ConexionReporte<Pedido>();
    try {
        **conexionReporte.generarReporte(pedidos, parametros, "PedidoImpresion");** //El error indica esta línea
        conexionReporte.ventanaReporte.setLocationRelativeTo(transaccionPedido);
        conexionReporte.ventanaReporte.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Cuando llamo al `PedidoReporte.jrxml`  la impresión no se realiza porque la consola indica el siguiente error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IErrorHandlingPolicy;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ICompilerRequestor;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IProblemFactory;)V
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileUnits(JRJdtCompiler.java:154)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:226)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:344)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:609)
at iOS.controlador.util.ConexionReporte.generarReporte(ConexionReporte.java:32)
at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.imprimir(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:427)
at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.guardar(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:498)
at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.actionPerformed(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:603)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at iOS.vista.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedido$1.run(TransaccionPedido.java:64)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**LO QUE PROBÉ**
Ya actualicé la versión de Eclipse.
Ya actualicé las librerías a las más recientes.
Ya actualicé la versión de JasperSoft.
Ejecutando el depurador, todos los parámetros del método `generarReporte` están debidamente cargados.

Buscando una solución me encontré con la posibilidad de ser un conflicto entre versiones pero aún no logro avances.

**EDIT**

Siguiendo las indicaciones de @Sal, me puse a usar el `.jasper` al momento de generar mi documento

```
public void generarReporte(List<E> lista, Map<String, Object> parametros,String nombreReporte) throws JRException {
    ventanaReporte.setSize(1000, 700);
    ventanaReporte.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ventanaReporte.setModal(true);
    
    InputStream stream = ConexionReporte.class.getResourceAsStream("/iOS/vista/impresiones/"+ nombreReporte + ".jasper");
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
    JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(print, true);
    ventanaReporte.getContentPane().add(viewer.getContentPane());
}
```

La linea de código que indica el error es la línea

```
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
```

El error que lanza luego de ejecutar el código es el que sigue:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte no válido 1 de la secuencia UTF-8 de 1 bytes
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:307)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:286)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:275)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:249)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:342)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:609)
at iOS.controlador.util.ConexionReporte.generarReporte(ConexionReporte.java:32)
at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.imprimir(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:427)
at iOS.controlador.ventanas.transacciones.TransaccionPedidoControlador.guardar(TransaccionPedidoControlador.java:498)
```

Leyendo encontré que podría ser porque mi documento contiene caracteres inválido para UTF-8 pero no encontré alguno que pudiera causar problemas.

Comment: Prueba primero usando el `.jasper` en lugar del `.jrxml`. No hay necesidad de compilar cada ejecución.

Comment: Al utilizar .jasper me lanza un error, edito la pregunto para incluir el error y la línea de código.

Comment: La idea es no compilar, el `.jasper` ya está compilado; no llames a `compileReport()` y manda el InputStream directamente al `fillReport()`.